# Getting or setting ngValue for select on change event

Tags: html-select, angular-reactive-forms

I am moving some code with the select from ngModel to reactive form and trying to get a selected option as an object. But I cannot know how to get and set up the selected 'item' object to 'myControl'.

```
        <form [formGroup]="myForm">
          <select id="myControl" name="myControl" formControlName="myControl"
          (change)="onChangeItem($event.target.value)" required
          [compareWith]="compareFn">
            <label for="myControl">My Text*</label>
            <option *ngFor="let item of items"
             [ngValue]="item">
             {{item.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </form>
```

In the ts file, I have

```
item = {id: number; name: string};
items = [list of items];
myForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  myControl: [undefined, [CustomValidators.required()]]
},{ updateOn: 'blur' });
compareFn(f1: any, f2: any): boolean {
  return f1.id === f2.id;
}

onChangeItem(value: string) {
  console.log(value); //  for example result will be like "5: Object"
  setInterval(() => { // may be it's not a nessasary just fot test
    console.log(this.myForm.controls.myControl.value); // here value doesn't change and equal the previous one 
    // logic with new selected value 
    this.myForm.controls.myControl.setValue(new value); // if it's not changed automaticaly    
  }, 100);
}
```

I can get id value as string from the `$event.target.value` after writing for option (`[value]= "item.id"`) and find the object from items by id but in this case, I have to store in myControl a string, not the object that I am interested for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach was about using data-attributes in the option tag

```
       <select 
        formControlName="myControl"
        (change)="onChangeItem(+$event.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.value)"
        required>
        <option *ngFor="let item of items"
          [ngValue]="item" [attr.data-value]="item.id">
          {{item.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

Then

```
  onChangeItem(id: number) {
    const curItem = this.items.find(value => value.id === id);
    this.myForm.controls.myControl.setValue(curItem)
  }
```

Bur after I figured out that the problem was in the trigger `updateOn: blur` and after I removed it will allow me to get current value on user change of select

```
 onChangeItem() {
    console.log(this.myForm.controls.myControl.value);
  }
```